# Extensions for Company News

Tags: extensions

We are developing our Magento site and wished to migrate over our company news stories.

Can anyone suggest a good extension to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Use **News by CommerceLab** extension. It's FREE and user friendly.

You can check it's functions, features and screenshots [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab.html).

Comment: Hi Just tried this and its not compatible with the latest version of Magento (v1) 1.9.2.4.

Comment: I don't think so. Don't forget to add Block and Variable(if any) to `System > Permissions > Blocks` and `System > Permissions > Variables` respectively. O/w call them for support